# where do I get a gazebo diff drive plugin?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I was previously using the erratic diff drive plugin here:
http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arrg/ua_controllers/erratic_gazebo_plugins

but it looks like it moved. bummer.

So I see that there seems to be code that does something similar in gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_diffdrive.cpp

however, it doesn't get built as a .so for some reason, instead it's a binary in /bin that doesn't seem to do anything.  Any idea how to get a basic diff drive robot running in gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9236/where-do-i-get-a-gazebo-diff-drive-plugin?/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Jeff,

You can still get the plug-in from ua-ros-pkg repository, it moved here:

http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_gazebo_plugins/

The whole erratic_robot stack is now available for download from your Ubuntu package manager (if you use Ubuntu that is).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-05-23**:
that is misleading, I've ticketed it (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4967).  Thanks.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-03-01**:
I am not exactly sure why it's implemented as a node and not a proper gazebo plugin that you add to your urdf file, that's what our implementation in ua-ros-pkg is. As far as I remember we had some trouble deleting and respawning robot on the fly in simulation, so we implemented diffdrive as a proper gazebo plugin. I think they both should work equally well for you.

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-03-01**:
Is the binary in gazebo_plugins the recommended way of implementing diff drive in a new robot?  I had previously used the ua-ros-pkg one because it was the first thing I found...

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-03-01**:
Diffdrive plugin that comes with gazebo_plugins package is written as a standalone ROS node, you have to launch it the way you launch any other regular ROS node, e.g. add this to your launch file:

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-02-28**:
Thanks! This will get me running again. Still, I wonder what's up with the diffdrive binary in gazebo_plungins...